# Alexa Custom Skill isn't inserting items into DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

Tired to follow the high low game pattern, but somehow the dynamodb isn't picking up any insertion??

I'm using a response interceptor that will save some session data into dynamodb under some condition, as following:

```java
    @Override
    public void process(HandlerInput handlerInput, Optional<Response> optional) {
        var sessionAttributes = handlerInput.getAttributesManager().getSessionAttributes();

        var sessionState = (String)sessionAttributes.get((Constants.STATE));
        var oldState = (String)sessionAttributes.get(Constants.STATE_OLD);

        // Update persistent storage whenever there's a change
        if (!oldState.equals(sessionState)) {
            handlerInput.getAttributesManager().setPersistentAttributes(new HashMap<>(){{
                put(Constants.STATE, sessionState);
            }});

            sessionAttributes.put(Constants.STATE_OLD, sessionState);
            logger.info("Persistent state updated");
        }
        logger.info("SaveSessionInterceptor called");
    }
```

And in the main streamHandler

```java
private static Skill getSkill() {
        logger.info("Skill Stream Handler Initialized");

        return Skills.standard()
                .withSkillId(config.ALEXA_SKILL_ID)
                .addRequestHandlers(
                   // handlers
                )
                .addResponseInterceptor(new SaveSessionInterceptor())
                // Add persistent storage support
                .withAutoCreateTable(true)
                .withTableName("AudioAdventure")
                .build();

    }
```

On AWS, the table's been created but just isn't responding to insertion through the persistent attributes.

Maybe I'm been doing sth wrong..

Comment: nvm, I was blind.. need to call `attributesManager.savePersistentAttributes`

Comment: Yes, I've run into that myself. The required one-two combo of setPersistentAttributes(attributes) and then savePersistentAttributes() can be a bit confusing and will get you across the persistence adapters. Glad you figured it out.